# Why a web page looks responsive offline in my laptop and it isn't anymore when I upload it with Filezilla?

Tags: css, filezilla

I added some media queries in CSS.file to make the web page responsive and it works great offline. But when I upload it on the server with Filezilla, it doesn't look responsive anymore.

I've already tried to change `@media only screen and (...)` in `@media (...)`.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
    .column_left {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .column_right {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .foto {
        width: 150px;
        height: 75px;
    }
    footer {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .title {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .subtitle {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2500px) {
    .foto {
        width: 150px;
        height: 75px;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stay Culture</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stile.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dokdo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: have you check if your css is correctly update? check if media queries works using browser inspect

Comment: Thanks so much! It's strange because other users saw it responsive with their devices. I inspected the browser and in ccs file I didn't find any media query. I clicked on 'sources' and added them and the browser read them. But it's weird because the css uploaded on the server has the media queries otherwise nobody could see the web page responsive. It seems that only my browser can't read the file updated. Maybe something connected with cache memory?

Comment: Please post your head section for the page.

Comment: I've edited the post adding head section.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with [cache](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en-us).

You can run `Ctrl+Shift+R` or `Ctrl+F5` to delete cache from the current opened page.

To avoid using of old cached files, you can simply add a 'version' tag at the end.
Like that:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stile.css?v=001">
```

This 'forces' file to reload, so it's recommended if any change was made in that file, because users are not going to run `Ctrl+F5` on your page.